# What ways are there to support multiple languages for an ASP.NET website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I want to translate my website to French, without using the Google translation API at run time.

Are there any built-in ways in ASP.NET to allow you support multiple languages?

Comment: so what do you want to use? do you want to have multiple languages in your site and load the correct one depending on user selection or who does the translation?

Comment: any other ways to translate webpage to different langauges?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're running an ASP.NET site, you should be able to use [resource files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for localisation.

For each bit of text (e.g. title, paragraph etc.) you define a field in a resource file. You can then create one resource file per language, which you can swap depending on which language you require.